# Apply lambda to populate column with mean from columns left of given column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

Given:

```
d = {'col1': [1,2], 'col2': [2,2], 'col3': [3,2], 'col4': [np.nan,np.nan], 'col5': [1,2], 'col6': [2,2], 'col7': [3,2], 'col8': [np.nan,np.nan]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df

   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6  col7  col8
0     1     2     3   NaN     1     2     3   NaN
1     2     2     2   NaN     2     2     2   NaN
```

what lambda could be applied to populate `col4` with mean of `col1`, `col2`, and `col3`, and populate `col8` with mean of `col5`, `col6`, and `col7`--in one statement?

Answer (score 0):

```
df['col4'] = df[['col1', 'col2','col3']].mean(axis=1)
df['col8'] = df[['col5', 'col6','col7']].mean(axis=1)
```

Chained

```
 df[['col4', 'col8']]=df[['col1', 'col2','col3']].mean(axis=1),df[['col5', 'col6','col7']].mean(axis=1)
df
```

Or slice and apply mean

```
df.iloc[:,:3].mean(axis=1)
df.iloc[:,-4:-1].mean(axis=1)
```

Tied together

```
 df[['col4', 'col8']]=df.iloc[:,:3].mean(axis=1),df.iloc[:,-4:-1].mean(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use a lambda you can do:

```
df['mean1'] = df.apply(lambda row: np.mean(row['col1'],row['col2'],row['col3']),axis=1)
df['mean1'] = df.apply(lambda row: np.mean(row['col5'],row['col6'],row['col7']),axis=1)
```

Alternatively you can do in one line like the below using pandas .mean though I think it's clearer on two lines

```
df['mean1'], df['mean2'] = df[['col1','col2','col3']].mean(axis=1), df[['col5','col6','col7']].mean(axis=1)
```